# Hide the console window when running mono applications on OS X

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin

I'm writing a headless Mono application on OS X and would like to hide the (redundant) console terminal window when it runs. The closest option I could find was setting **Compile Target** from *Executable* to *Executable with GUI*, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer accidentally when I created a project using the **Empty Project** template vs **Console Project** template: there's a project file setting called `Externalconsole`. Deleting it made the console go away, but I can't find any formal documentation for it or the equivalent switch in the Xamarin Studio GUI.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Externalconsole>true</Externalconsole>
  </PropertyGroup>
```